# WPF Control to emulate Outlook Attachment-View

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to get the ListView to look like the MS Outlook Attachment-Control. I've already got the horizontal scrolling, but it still displays only one item in a row.

How can I get it to look like this?
[image]

What I've achieved so far:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdAttachments"
      Grid.Row="4"
      Grid.Column="1"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="45" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Margin="3,0,0,0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Cursor="Hand"
               Text="Angefügt:" />

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
        <ListBox x:Name="libAttachments"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}"
                 MouseDoubleClick="lvAttachments_MouseDoubleClick">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding MimeTypeIcon}" Stretch="None" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding File.Name}" />
                        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu.Items>
                                    <MenuItem Click="btnOpenAttachment_Click" Header="Öffnen">
                                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                                            <Image Source="/Images/magnifier.png" Stretch="None" />
                                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem Click="btnSaveAttachment_Click" Header="Speichern unter">
                                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                                            <Image Source="/Images/disk-black.png" Stretch="None" />
                                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </ContextMenu.Items>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you set on using a listview? Seems like it would be easier to use an ItemsControl in a WrapPanel

Comment: @ChrisW. I'm set to use whatever control it takes to get what I want :)

Comment: are you using MVVM or are you wanting this as a custom control or...?

Comment: @Firoso I'm actually not using it as a custom control yet. I'm planning on using it as one eventually, though. But for now I'd hope to just get it working.

Comment: I've given you a good explanation of the primary considerations, if you need to know more, you can contact me by email via my profile.

Comment: @Firoso I've seen it, thank you. I'm trying to get it working in my application at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so where it seems you got snagged up was with your ListBox still pushing things in single column fashion and the lack of ability to give you something to fire off say a click event. So what I had in mind was something more like this;

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="300" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Margin="5,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <Image Source="{Binding MimeTypeIcon}" Stretch="None" />
                       <HyperlinkButton Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding File.Name}" />
                   </StackPanel>          
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I wasn't to sure what you were trying to do with your magnifier and disk though I see your Clicks for them, but you can add those to this layout however you like, just a note though, I just free-handed this between meetings so never built it but should work fine. If not we'll plug at it again. Main differences are changing to a hyperlinkbutton to give you click and some other subtle differences from Firoso's but his is still technically sound, or should be anyway :)

Comment: Thank you for your post. I don't need a click event, I just need a "SelectedItem" property (or something similar). The click events were just for the items' ContextMenu

Comment: Sadly the ItemsControl doesn't have a SelectedItem or SelectedIndex property... This works fine in all occurences, however I still need one of those two properties :(

Comment: You need to implement against a Selector instead of a ListBox then

Comment: @Firoso You mean a selector instead of the itemscontrol?

Comment: Yes. that should provide the functionality.

Comment: @Firoso I get this compile error: `The type "Selector" is abstract and must include an explicit value.` and `Type 'Selector' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter.`

Comment: Right because selector is an abstract type :-P  I meant you're going to have to implement against something in that family that provides your behavior.  Try a ListBox still but set the ItemsControl.ItemPanel attached property of the ListBox to Wrap Panel.

Comment: Updated to address this case, see above.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is an [ListBox](http://wpftutorial.net/ListBox.html) with a custom ItemsPanel.

```
    <ListBox>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

The snippet above configures a ListBox to use a [WrapPanel](http://wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html) as the layout provider or "ItemsPanel" for the items it is to present.  From there it may make sense to implement a custom Item Container style, and/or custom Data Templates. You could easily apply a DataTemplate as you did above if you are using an MVVM pattern and data binding to a collection (preferably observable)

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding MimeTypeIcon}" Stretch="None" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding File.Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

To complete this picture, a scroll viewer can be used so long as it's height is constrained by either a parent layout control (Grid.Row = 1 where RowDefinition Height="constant") or my an explicit height being set on the ScrollViewer.

My final solution based on yours looks like this:

```
     <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}"
        MouseDoubleClick="lvAttachments_MouseDoubleClick"
        SelectionMode="Single">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding MimeTypeIcon}" Stretch="None" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding File.Name}" />
                        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu.Items>
                                    <MenuItem Click="btnOpenAttachment_Click" Header="Öffnen">
                                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                                            <Image Source="/Images/magnifier.png" Stretch="None" />
                                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem Click="btnSaveAttachment_Click" Header="Speichern unter">
                                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                                            <Image Source="/Images/disk-black.png" Stretch="None" />
                                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </ContextMenu.Items>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

A few things to note:  When possible, consider using [Commands](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) instead of events, they can lead to looser coupling.  Introducing a [Behavior](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html) might even make sense if the behavior it's self is something that you might have other places in your project or re-usability is ideal.

Comment: Well, it's just supposed to do what the outlook attachment-bar does. Most of it is clear from my posted code and the bindings. So it displays a mimetype-icon and the filename just like outlook does.

Comment: Ya Firoso got up exactly what I what I was hinting at before me so +1, then you'd just have to dump that in a fixed height scrollviewer and voila!

Comment: Just remember to Disable the horizontal Scrollbar in the Scrollviewer or your wrappanel won't wrap and will extend indefinitely. Then you're golden, cheers firoso!

Comment: I might be missing something incredibly easy, but `<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` still shows it in one row and doesn't wrap

Comment: That's what I get for not testing...  Hmm, I'll come back and take a look, try investigating using Snoop, I assume that the wrap panel / items control is taking on the wrong size.

Comment: I've just posted my entire code in the first post so you might see if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Ditch your listbox, you don't need it ;)

Comment: Sadly the ItemsControl doesn't support the `SelectedItem` property. Additionally, the Itemscontrol still does not scroll

Comment: Ok you caught me at lunch and I have a meeting when I get back to the office, when I get some free time we'll get you sorted out. No worries, there's always a way :)

Comment: @ChrisW. alright, thank you very much :-) It's 8pm here, so I might not respond immediately.

Comment: @Firoso Thank you again for your update and sorry if I'm bothering you.. But your edit answer now still scrolls horizontal instead of vertical (and thus doesn't wrap)